# How to display user's time zone information nicely in javascript

Tags: javascript, timezone

In a web page, using Javascript, I want to display the user's local timezone information nicely. For instance, if a user from California (Pacific time) browses the web page, I want to display something like this:

```
Pacific Standard Time
```

If the long time zone name is not available then at least I want to display 'PST' in this case.

Is there a standard way to do this in Javascript? I've looked around, but couldn't find a satisfactory solution. The Date object's toLocaleString method comes close, but it's not quite what I want.

Comment: Unfortunately, any of the below methods that pull out part of the response from `.toString()` will give you inconsistent results, because the implementations are slightly different in some browsers, especially older ones.

Answer (score 2):

How about this one ? you can add some conditions around it but the basic is

```
var now = new Date();
var tz = now.toString().split("GMT")[1];
tz.substr(7,tz.length -8)
```

OR

```
var now = new Date(); 
var zone = /\(.*\)/.exec(now.toString())[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably looking for is a simple code snippet. However, working with date formatting is an area that is greatly helped by using a good tool, and Moment.js is in my opinion, the best: http://momentjs.com/

Or, you can do this

```
var myDate = new Date(); 
var timeZone = /\(.*\)/.exec(myDate.toString())[1];
```

Comment: Moment.js is a great tool. Actually I had taken a look at its document too, but I couldn't find what I wanted. @Harvey, can you be  more specific about Moment.js?

Comment: Jake, it's not the best tool to do exactly what you requested. That's why I amended my answer with a simple way to print the time zone. It's a tool that's designed to format dates, compare them, and to convert dates from one time zone to another.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking fore something like:

```
console.log(new Date().toString());
```

For an easy to read list of Date Object methods see: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp .